# Ionic3 - iOS - Slide Menu Styling Issues

Tags: ios, css, ionic3

I am having an issue with my app's sliding menu (segment) buttons. Two of the three buttons text are filled blocks, and I did not make any recent style changes to the app, let alone the `app.scss` file.

I am only seeing this on iOS devices (using an iPad mini and iPhone XS), not on `ionic serve` and Xcode simulators.

Is there a way to figure out the cause of this styling issue, or at least replicate the bug on either the Xcode simulators or `ionic serve`. I tried development and production builds, no difference.

My only guess is maybe something dealing with the new changes made with iOS Mojave as it made changes to the iOS app structure.

[image: From the iPhone XS]

Answer (score 0):

I am using a work-around by changing the font color to something close to the original.

Ex.
`#777` to `#777776`

There has to be a reason it is doing this with just `#777` or `#fff`.